# Spring boot: Sending a JSON to a post request that uses a model as a param

Tags: spring, spring-boot, post

Lets say I have a predefined post mapping as such:

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/add", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> addVal(@RequestBody final valDetail newVal) {
        //Do Stuff
    }
```

and the `valDetail` object as follows:

```
@Data
@Component
@Entity
@Table(name = "val_portal")
public class valDetail {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "valcode")
    private String valCode;
    @Column(name = "valname")
    private String valName;
   }
```

How would I go about actually sending JSON values from a separate service to this `/add` endpoint so that they are properly received as a `valDetail` object?
Currently I tried this implementation but I keep getting a 415 response code.

```
JSONObject valDetail = new JSONObject();
valDetail.put("valCode",request.getAppCode().toLowerCase());
valDetail.put("valName", request.getProjectName());

 String accessToken = this.jwtUtility.retrieveToken().get("access_token").toString();
HttpHeaders authHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
authHeaders.setBearerAuth(accessToken);
authHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(valDetail.toString(), authHeaders);

ResponseEntity<String> loginResponse = restTemplate.exchange(uri,
                        HttpMethod.POST,
                        entity,
                        String.class);
```

Comment: Have you tried `@PostMapping(value = "/add", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)`? If you call this endpoint via Postman with a JSON body does it work?

Comment: This endpoint already works via Postman with a JSON body, also I am not allowed to change this endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass data as json you don't want to take `Model` try to use `@ResponseBody` annotation to transfer data through json.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/add", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> addVal(@RequestBody final valDetail newVal) {
    //Do Stuff
}
```

Comment: Sadly I am not allowed to change the ```/add``` endpoint.

Comment: but why would you change url

Comment: I am not allowed to edit that service, It has to be used as is.